# A simple Python iterator going in to infinite loop

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield

I was trying to write a simple countdown iterator of my own, I implemented a `__iter__()` function and the corresponding `__next__()` to support the iterator.I have used a `yield` function inside the `__next__()` function to return a new value everytime I iterate over the object.
When I use `yield`, the code goes over in an infinite loop as compared to using `return` statement.
Following is my code:

```
class MyIterator():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        print("In the next function")
        if self.value > 0:
            yield self.value
            self.value -= 1
        else:
            raise StopIteration("Failed to proceed to the next step")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    myIt = MyIterator(10)
    for i in myIt:
        print(i)
```

And the O/P is  as follows:

```
  <generator object __next__ at 0x101181990>
  <generator object __next__ at 0x1011818e0>
  <generator object __next__ at 0x101181990>
  <generator object __next__ at 0x1011818e0>

  and so on for infinite times....
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `__next__` method should **not** itself be a generator. Replace `yield` with `return`:

```
def __next__(self):
    print("In the next function")
    if self.value > 0:
        return_value = self.value
        self.value -= 1
        return return_value
    else:
        raise StopIteration("Failed to proceed to the next step")
```

Note that you still need to decrease `self.value` after determining what is to be returned, hence the use of a separate `return_value` variable.

Any function (or method) with `yield` in it will produce a generator object when called, and that generator is then the iterable. Such an object then has an `__iter__` method that returns `self` and a `__next__` method that will produce the next value when called. This is why you see the `<generator object __next__ at 0x1011818e0>` object being printed each time `__next__` is called.

However, for your object to be an iterable itself, your `__next__` method should instead return *the next value in the sequence*. It'll be called repeatedly until it raises `StopIteration`. This is different from using `yield`, it should return immediately, not defer until later!

Demo:

```
>>> class MyIterator():
...     def __init__(self,value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return self
...     def __next__(self):
...         print("In the next function")
...         if self.value > 0:
...             return_value = self.value
...             self.value -= 1
...             return return_value
...         else:
...             raise StopIteration("Failed to proceed to the next step")
...
>>> myIt = MyIterator(10)
>>> for i in myIt:
...     print(i)
...
In the next function
10
In the next function
9
In the next function
8
In the next function
7
In the next function
6
In the next function
5
In the next function
4
In the next function
3
In the next function
2
In the next function
1
In the next function
```

If you wanted to use a generator function, make `__iter__` the generator, and use a loop:

```
class MyIterator():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def __iter__(self):
        value = self.value
        while value > 0:
            yield value
            value -= 1
```

However, this makes your `MyIterator` class an iterable, not an iterator. Instead, each time you use a `for` loop a *new* iterator is created (the `__iter__` generator object) that is then iterated over. Using `__next__` makes your object an iterator that can only be iterated over *once*.

Comment: This isn't going to work. It returns before decrementing so will infinite loop.

Comment: @BrianSchlenker: Yup, corrected. The core issue is the `yield` however.

Comment: Thank you!, so I am going in to __iter__ of generator created by yield and then to my __iter__ in an infinite loop, which is why I keep seeing the following 2 lines repeatedly ?     `<generator object __next__ at 0x101d818e0>
<generator object __next__ at 0x101d81990>`

Comment: @AparnaChaganti: the memory address repeats because memory is freed each time the reference to the generator object is cleared. So you see the same two addresses again and again as the previous object is freed when the next object is created.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am sorry, can you be more descriptive? I am probably too weak to understand what you just said now.

Comment: @AparnaChaganti: The hex number in `<generator object __next__ at 0x101d818e0>` is the memory address of the object on the heap. All Python objects live on the heap, and only live as long as there is still a reference to it. Here the reference is `i`, and only when you assign a new object is assigned to `i` (like the next `__next__` call result, `<generator object __next__ at 0x101d81990>`) can the other object be freed again. Python then can re-use that chunk of memory, which is why you see the numbers repeat.

Comment: Wow !, reuse the same address again ? Can I apply the same concept for any other generator ? Lets take the example of iterating a simple list, should I expect only two addresses ( from heap ) to be consumed all through the iteration, since the reference to the previous generator objects gets freed immediately after I make a call to the next one ?

Comment: @AparnaChaganti: That you produced generator objects here was *not what you wanted to do*. That said, you use generators (iterators), because they let you process data in a memory-efficient manner. Items can be processed one by one so previous intermediary results are freed from the heap and yes, that can lead to memory being reused.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks again !

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of confusion here.  When you using *yield*, you don't need to create an iterator class.  The generator already is an iterator.

So, change the *yield* to a *return* and it will do what you want :-)

Also, you will need to update `self.value` *before* the `return`.  Here is what the fixed-up code looks like:

```
class MyIterator():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        print("In the next function")
        value = self.value
        if value > 0:
            self.value -= 1
            return value
        else:
            raise StopIteration("Failed to proceed to the next step")
```

And here is how to do the same thing with a generator:

```
def my_iterator(value):
    while value > 0:
        yield value
        value -= 1
```

As you can see, generators make a programmer's life much easier :-)

Comment: Thank you ! much appreciated